# Link to file in the parent folder

Tags: bibliographies, paths, filesystem-access, folders

I have a folder, say `C:\example\paper` with a bib-file `C:\example\1.bib`.

I also have  a tex file `C:\example\paper\main.tex` where I would like to put a link to `1.bib`. I can put the whole path, of course, but I wonder if there is a method to put link for a parent folder `C:\example` from its subfolder `C:\example\paper`?

Comment: On a Unix system `\bibliography{../1}` works; it should also on Windows.

Comment: Which Windows version and which filesystem (NTFS or FAT) are you using?

Comment: I use Windows 7 with NTFS. @egreg, your example works, thanks. Will you write it as an answer?

Comment: Also auxiliary generated previously should be cleaned before compiling the tex file again. Or you may get the error message that the bib file can not be found.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

One can refer to the parent folder by `../` both on Unix systems and in Windows; therefore

```
\bibliography{../1}
```

will work for the bibliography file `1.bib` that resides in the parent folder.

Note that paths on Windows are expressed with `\`, but for TeX related programs the slash `/` works in its place and is of course preferable.

Comment: It is strange but this method of relative addressing stopped working when I moved to WinEdt 10.3 although it still works with WinEdt 9. MikTeX 2.9 is used on same laptop in both cases.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov I've never used WinEdt, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on egreg's answer: in case you include your BibTeX file inside a file *which is itself included in the preamble*, you must keep the path relative to the preamble, *not* that file.

Concretely, say your file structure looked like this:

```
C:\example\
    1.bib
    paper\
        main.tex
        preamblestuff\
             bibstuff.tex
```

then if `main.tex` calls `\input{./preamblestuff/bibstuff.tex}` and the latter contains `\addbibresource{...}`, the path to the bib file should *still* be `../1.bib` as given in egreg's answer, *not* `../../1.bib` (which you would otherwise think to be correct from the point of view of `bibstuff.tex`).

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. It helped me.