# How to choose bibliography location or path to be different from the default one

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, texshop

I want to change the path of my .bib file to be in a separate location, so instead of writing this:

```
\bibliography{refh}
```

I want it to be on any other location like this:

```
\bibliography{~//Deakin/My~Papers/refh}
```

Note: I'm a mac user so if anyone could please assist me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can use relativ paths. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29172/link-to-file-in-the-parent-folder or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6805/bib-library-file-in-a-different-directory-how-to-use-mendeley-centralised-b

Comment: You can use `\string~` for denoting the home directory; but BibTeX doesn't work with spaces in file names.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.
Marco gave me the correct answer found here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29172/link-to-file-in-the-parent-folder, Thanks Marco