# Figures: Link to file in parent dictionary

Tags: biblatex, floats, bibtex, folders

I use LaTeX2e on Windows and Ubuntu and the computers are synced via cloud. Therefore I have the same files but different paths.
Is it possible to refer to the parent dictionary with a relative path so I can compile my documents on both Computers without having to change the path every time?

I only found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29172/link-to-file-in-the-parent-folder) solution for BibTeX but it doesn't work on BibLaTeX nor with figures.

Comment: Normally you can use relatives paths for included files, pictures and bibliography databases. I think there are some security restrictions that prevent LaTeX from *writing* in parent directories, but reading usually woks fine. Can you share a bit more about your directory setup, your document setup, what you want to do, what you tried and how it did not work for you, please?

Comment: I guess most people just put all the files for their project into a single directory and use relative paths. Then it is easy to move betweeen machines, because everything is in that one directory and the relatives paths always resolve all files correctly. If you are planning on using something like a global bibliography file or global picture include folders that should also be possible.

Comment: So typing `../` is too much work?

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is setting up a general BibLaTeX bibliography file which I want to use on Ubuntu and Win10. The problem can't be solved by setting `../` like @JohnKormylo suggested since the directory structure is totally different on Ubuntu.

Comment: Hrmm, if the relative/local file structure is different *and* the global file structure is different as well (since you have different systems), it is going to be quite hard to find a 'uniform' way to specify the same file. The only other thing that comes to mind is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38287/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67205/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/310365/35864